# EXTRAER CARACTERES DE UNA CADENA DE TEXTO SEPARADOS POR COMAS

Tags: c#, variables, textbox

espero estén muy bien. Requiero de su ayuda por favor.

Tengo esta cadena de texto en un TextBox en C#:

**O-07** RETENCIÓN EN LA FUENTE A TÍTULOS DE RENTA **, O-15** AUTORETENEDOR **, O-19** PRODUCTOS Y/O EXPORTADOR DE BIENES EXENTOS

Necesito guardar en una variable únicamente los primeros 4 caracteres que se encuentras justo después de la coma, es decir lo que que tengo en negrilla.

Le agradezco su ayuda, soy nuevo en esto y no se como hacerlo.

Comment: TextBox.Text.Split(',').Select(a=> a.Trim()[0..4]);

Comment: Gracias, no lo pude usar porque ese operador de intervalo solo esta disponible para versión 8.0 o posteriores de C#, y yo uso 7.3. Lo tendré muy presente cuando actualice mi versión, Gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más básica de la siguiente manera:

```
string cadena = "O-07 RETENCIÓN EN LA FUENTE A TÍTULOS DE RENTA , O-15 AUTORETENEDOR , O-19 PRODUCTOS Y/O EXPORTADOR DE BIENES EXENTOS";

string[] cadenas = cadena.Split(" , ");
string[] cuatroPrimerosCaracteres = new string[cadenas.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < cadenas.Length; i++)
{
    cuatroPrimerosCaracteres[i] = cadenas[i].Substring(0, 4);
    Console.WriteLine(cuatroPrimerosCaracteres[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

O de una forma mas completa, utilizando expresiones regulares y LINQ:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string cadena = "O-07 RETENCIÓN EN LA FUENTE A TÍTULOS DE RENTA , O-15 AUTORETENEDOR , O-19 PRODUCTOS Y/O EXPORTADOR DE BIENES EXENTOS";

IEnumerable<string> cadenas = new Regex(@"\s*,\s*").Split(cadena).Select(subcadena => subcadena.Substring(0,4));

foreach (var cuatroPrimerosCaracteres in cadenas)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cuatroPrimerosCaracteres);
}
```

Comment: Jorge muchas gracias, fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta. Saludos.